# Различное отображение расположение элемента относительного другого элемента в различных браузерах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, position

Элемент  имеет относительное позиционирование относительно блока. В браузерах яндекс и хром при текущих настройках отображается нормально, но в IE элемент значительно смещён в верх. При изменение настроек расположения под браузер IE в других браузерах элемент смещен в низ.

P.S. все браузеры обновлены

```
<div class='retturn'>
   <img class='r6' src='../images/tag.png'>
   <span>Цена: <br>от 9900 руб.</br></span>
</div>
```

---

```
.retturn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
}

.retturn span{
    display: inline-block; 
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;

    -moz-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    transform: rotate(-35deg);

    left: 0px;
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не вижу у тебя `top: 0`
Суть в том, что IE позиционирует от центра, а хром от левого верхнего края, поэтому нужно указывать `top и left` ну или `right и bottom`. Думаю суть понятна